# Spark transformations generate future dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datetime, impala

I have an ETL application that loads the data to Impala using Spark. In the process a set of columns is transformed. There is a timestamp column which is used to calculate date column of integer type. Thsi calculation looks like this:

```
df.select((col("date_time") / 1000).cast(TimestampType) as "ts")
.withColumn("date", date_format($"ts", "yyyyMMdd")
```

So when I load the data without any transformations or add timestamp transformations, there are no issues. But when the date transformation is added somehow it affects the resulting data and future dates get generated in both date and timestamp columns. What could be the reason of it?

Here is input:

```
2020-05-26 11:40:27.526
```

Expected result:

```
2020-05-26 11:40:27.526, 20200526
```

Actual transformation result:

```
2020-05-31 11:40:27.526,20200531
```

for some other dates even the year is changed:

```
2115-05-27 16:32:11.482,21150527
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that problem was quite trivial - future dates in the original raw data set. Dataset update fixed the problem